# Equality of shapeless extensible records depends on field order

Tags: scala, shapeless

These two records have the same fields with the same values but the order is different:

```
val person1 = ("age" ->> 34) :: ("name" ->> "Jane") :: HNil
val person2 = ("name" ->> "Jane") :: ("age" ->> 34) :: HNil
```

These are not considered equal when I use `==` because the order of the fields is different. They are `HList`s, so it  makes sense to me that the order matters when checking for equality, but I feel like records that are permutations of one another should be equal. I also feel like they should have the same type but they don't because they are `HList`'s.

Is there a way to get equality of values and types for records to act more like what I expect? Also, what are the reasons it is implemented this way?  Could `HMap`s have been used instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this using `Align`.

```
import shapeless._, syntax.singleton._, record._, ops.hlist._

def permutatedEqual[R1 <: HList, R2 <: HList](
  r1: R1, r2: R2
)(implicit
  align: Align[R1, R2]
): Boolean = align(r1) == r2
```

Which you can use as :

```
permutatedEqual(person1, person2) // Boolean = true
```

Comment: It looks like align can also be called directly on the `HList` like this:
`person1.align(person2)`